# delete all rows if the cell value does not start with cioi, 600t and htk4

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

i have to delete all rows other than the rows which starts with cioi, 600t and htk4 in column 4. my excel also has headers and it should not be deleted. In future this list my increase in that case can i add to my macro

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I had tried this but it is not working for multiple condition suppose in the below code I have mentioned two person names but when I run the macro it doesn't keep the data related to nitya

Comment: Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Set rng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("<>*Nitya*", "<>*Solaman*")
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
'find last populated row
xEndRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'iterate all rows from bottom to top
For I = xEndRow To 2 Step -1
   'get value of cell at current row and 4th column
   currentCellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 4).Value
   'get first 4 characters
   startsWith = Left(currentCellValue, 4)

   'if row doesnt met criteria, delete it
   If startsWith <> "cioi" And startsWith <> "600t" And startsWith <> "htk4" Then
       Rows(I).Delete
   End If

Next
```

you might want to make it more dynamic since everything is hard-coded due to lack of details in question.

Anyway, here's an image of my tested data before:

[image]

And after running the macro:

[image]

Comment: hi @mdelapena thanks a lot, can you provide the full code

Comment: hi @mdelapena thanks a lot, can you provide the full code

Comment: that is the full code, just add it to your workbook module, if you need help with that take a look to this [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) .

Comment: also, mark as the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir but it is working only working for first two values from third value it is deleting all rows... suppose I have given six values along with above 3 but it is keeping cioi,  600t and deleting all the remaining 4

Comment: can you post the sample data you are using?

Comment: no its working , i figured it , i used 5 letters hence it was not picking up.. thanks again